# Extract Json Data with screaming frog

Tags: json, regex, web-scraping, seo

I'm using Screaming Frog as a way to extract data from a Json generated from an URL.
The Json generated is this form :

```
{"ville":[{"codePostal":"13009","ville":"VAUFREGE","popin":"ouverturePopin","zoneLivraison":"1300913982","url":""},{"codePostal":"13009","ville":"LES BAUMETTES","popin":"ouverturePopin","zoneLivraison":"1300913989","url":""},{"codePostal":"13009","ville":"MARSEILLE 9EME ARRON","popin":"ouverturePopin","zoneLivraison":"1300913209","url":""}]}
```

I'm using this regex in Custom > Extraction in Screaming Frog as a way to extract the values of "codePostal".

"codePostal":".*?"

Problem is it doesn't extract anything.
When I test my regex in regex101, it seems correct.

Do you have any clue about what is wrong ? 
Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried to save the output to understand what ScreamingFrog sees? It doesn't matter - not at the beginning - whether your RegEx works. That said, don't forget that SF is a Java based tool hence it is the engine used by the reg ex, so make sure you test your regular expressions with the correct dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the output to understand what ScreamingFrog sees? It doesn't matter - not at the beginning - whether your RegEx works.

That said, don't forget that SF is a Java based tool hence it is the engine used by the reg ex, so make sure you test your regular expressions with the correct dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify group extractors enclosed in parentheses. For instance in your example, you need to have ("codePostal":".*?") as extractor.

In addition if you simply want to extract the value, you could use the following instead.
"codePostal":"(.*?)"

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with your Regular Expression. It seems to be that the problem is with the Content Type. ScreamingFrog isn't properly reading application/JSON content types for scraping. Hopefully they will fix this bug.